# What is the difference between cross-platform development and apps porting?

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, windows-phone, mobile-application

I have developed a cross-platform app using PhoneGap for iPhone and Android. I'm considering to make that app available to other platforms as well. I came across some of [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394031%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [BlackBerry](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/) documents about apps porting. This got me confused.

1. What is mobile apps porting?
2. What is the difference between apps porting and cross-platform development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Apps porting" is the process of taking an app developed for one platform and "porting" its functionality to another.  This is essentially re-development of an existing application.

"Cross-platform" development is the process of using a system like PhoneGap to develop an app once with a single development system, then compiling/generating targeted platform builds for multiple platforms.

Comment: What I was assuming is wrong then. 
Porting is not converting apps, it is re-development in one way or the other by reusing algorithms, resources etc. At the most basic level, there are no tools that can convert one platform apps to another. Is that right?

Comment: There are some tools that can do some basic conversion from one language to another, such as C# to Java.  In some limited cases those tools might be helpful, but for non-trivial applications (especially in mobile) those tools won't be much help.  There are too many environmental variables to automate a conversion process.